# Do touch on point where ray hits unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, touch, raycasting

I searched the whole internet, but couldn't find anything useful. I want to "do" a touch input on the position where a ray hits an object, and only if it hits something. I hope you understand what I mean, and I know that its not common to do it with a raycast, but I need it this way for the htc vive. Thanks in advance.
or easier said, how can I touch on the screen from my script, means without really touching the screen?

Answer (score 1):

You can use camera.ScreenToWorldPoint (new Vector3 (position that you want to check clicking)) in your code.

```
        //you can change the start position in your code.
        var startPos =
             camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(2,2, 10));
```

then you can use this function for detecting clicking without real clicking.

```
public void CalculateEndPositions(Vector3 start)
{
    //forward
    var rayForward = new Ray(start, Vector3.up);
    Debug.DrawRay(start,Vector3.up, Color.green);
    RaycastHit rayForwardInfo;

    if (Physics.Raycast(rayForward, out rayForwardInfo))
    {
       Debug.Log("Collider Name = " + rayForwardInfo.collider.name);
    }

}
```

I hope this code is usefull for you.